# GatsbyJS + TypeScript: Property 'allDocu' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I'm trying to create a node for each "docu" and then create a page for each "docu" but I can't understand why I get this error: Property 'allDocu' does not exist on type '{}'.

This is my code in gatsby-node.ts

```
import { graphql, type GatsbyNode } from "gatsby"
import path from "path"

type Docu = {
    key: string
    continent: string
    title: string
    subtitle: string
    docuCoverImg: string
    resume: string
    blurb: string
    country: string
    startDate: string
    endDate: string
    cost: string
    video: string
    itinerary: {
        num: string
        name: string
        description: string
        dayImgIcon: string
        dayCoverImg: string
    }[]
    itinerary_map: string
    is_fishing: boolean
    fishing_details: {
        target: string
        technique: string
        equipment: {
            rod: string
            reel: string
            line: string
            lure: string
            lineSchema: string
        }
    }
    water: string
    location: string
    fishingVideo: string
    fishingPhotos: {
        photo0: string
        photo1: string
        photo2: string
    }
  }

export const sourceNodes: GatsbyNode["sourceNodes"] = async ({ 
  actions,
  createNodeId,
  createContentDigest,
 }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const data1 = require('./src/data/all_docus.json');

  data1.forEach((docu: Docu) => {
    const node = {
      ...docu,
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      id: createNodeId(`docu_${docu.key}_${docu.title}`),
      internal: {
        type: "Docu",
        content: JSON.stringify(docu),
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(docu),
      },
    }
    createNode(node)
  })
}


// query for docus and create pages
export const createPages: GatsbyNode["createPages"] = async ({
  actions,
  graphql,
  reporter,
 }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const basePath = "/"
  const archiveTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Archive.tsx")
  createPage({
    path: basePath,
    component: archiveTemplate,
  }) 
  
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allDocu {
        nodes {
          id
          key
          title
          subtitle
          continent
          country
          cost
          docuCoverImg
          blurb
          resume
          startDate
          endDate
          video
          itinerary {
            num
            name
            description
            dayCoverImg
            dayImgIcon
          }
          itinerary_map
          is_fishing
          fishing_details {
            target
            technique
            location
            water
            fishingVideo
            fishingPhotos {
              photo0
              photo1
              photo2
            }
            equipment {
              rod
              reel
              lure
              line
              lineSchema
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild("ERROR: Loading 'createPages' query", result.errors)
    return
  }

  const docus = result.data?.allDocu.nodes
  const singleDocuTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Single_docu.tsx")
  docus.forEach((docu: { title: any }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `docus/${docu.title}`,
      component: singleDocuTemplate,
      context: { id: docu.title },
    })
  })  

}
```

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks,
Davide

I tried different solution but noone works.
I would like to get a page created for each "docu"